# Mongoid upsert fields

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I would like to use the mongoid's upsert method but it should check the document existence on fields different than _id (mongoimport command allows you to do this with --upsertFields option).
Is there a way to do this with mongoid?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question, this should work as expected:

```
person = Person.find_or_create_by(somefield: somefield)
person.update_attributes(otherfield: otherfield, somethingelse: somethingelse)
```

Comment: this works but it's not the final solution for me 'cause it takes too long ( 50seconds vs 3seconds of mongoimport). any alternative solutions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Actually, mongoid has already packaged into the your_model.collection.method.so you can do upsert like this:

```
Person.collection.update_one({main_key: value}, {"$set":{key: value}}, {upsert: true})
```